# Strange behaviour on "which" clause for matching string composed of number plus empty space on R

Tags: r, string-matching

I was checking in a dataframe imported from an xlsx file which values where numeric. I have found that I have a strange behaviour trying to match some fields that have a number followed by empty spaces:

```
> hcis$CODIGO_3[127890]
[1] "505227  "

> which(hcis$CODIGO_3==hcis$CODIGO_3[127890])
[1] 127890

> which(hcis$CODIGO_3=="505227  ")
integer(0)
```

Why is this happening? How could try to get the row number of this value if I cannot use which in these causes?

Update based on comment:

```
> charToRaw(hcis$CODIGO_3[127890])
 [1] 35 30 35 32 32 37 c2 a0 c2 a0

> charToRaw("505227  ")
[1] 35 30 35 32 32 37 20 20
```

Comment: Can't tell from your example but it's most likely caused by a non-printing character.  Compare the output of `charToRaw(hcis$CODIGO_3[127890])` to `charToRaw("505227  ")`.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the reason behind the behaviour.

Is there anyway to read the excel file in a way that I minimize the possiblity of these non-printing characters?

Comment: Which package are you using to read the data?  Try using `readxl::read_excel()` as it strips whitespace by default although I'm not certain whether it treats non-breaking spaces (`\u00A0`) as whitespace.  If it doesn't you can remove it using `trimws(hcis$CODIGO_3, whitespace = "[\\h\\v]")` or alternatively use `readr::parse_number()` to convert to numeric.

Comment: I have used hcis = read_excel("file.xlsx", col_types = rep("text", 48)) I forced column types to text because otherwise CODIGO_3 was only importing NAs (80% of the column content is indeed composed of NAs).